# Advanced Find in Excel 2013?

Tags: regex, microsoft-excel-2013

For the life of me I can't find or find a way to enable "advanced find" in Excel Pro 2013. I have a fairly simple find/replace that I need to do, just locating all entries contained within parentheses and deleting that portion of the text from the cell (so this statement would be "replaced" with nothing).

I used to use either wildcards or a regular expression if needed, but advanced find, as far as I can tell, does not exist in Excel 2013.

Is this the case, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default wildcards are enabled for a Search Replace Dialog (if you change the 'Format' to Text then wildcards are switched off). Therefore you should simply be able to do:

```
Find what: (*)
Replace with:
```

And that'll clear all your values in parenthesis.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.